# In group $G$, $a^m = e$ implies $|a| \mid m$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove this lemma in group theory.

> For $a \in G$, if $a^m = e$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then the order of $a$ must divide $m$.

*Proof.* For a contradiction, suppose the order of $a$, denoted $b$,  does not divide $m$. By the Euclidean algorithm, we may write 
$$m = nb + r$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 < r < b$. That $r > 0$ follows from the assumption toward a contradiction. (Otherwise, it could be the case that $b \mid m$.) We have: 
\begin{align*}
a^m = a^{nb + r} = a^{nb} a^r = a^{nb} a^r = (a^b)^n a^r = e^n a^r = a^r.
\end{align*} 
Since $r < b$, and $b$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^b = e$, $a^r \neq e$, so $a^m \neq e$, a contradiction. Hence, we have $r = 0$, so $b \mid m$.

Comment: +1, looks good to me. For more clarity, I would start the main equation with $e = a^m$ and note you repeated one of the steps exactly.

Comment: Correct, but the ending is superfluous, weaving into more contradictions. As soon as you find $a^r = e$ with $r < b$ you have your contradiction. No need to extend the discussion further.

Comment: You do not need to phrase it like a proof by contradiction. The Euclidean algorithm gives you $m=nb+r$ with $r=0$ or $0\lt r\lt b$. The final calculation shows that you must have $r=0$, hence $n|m$, which is what you want to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems correct to me. Generally, proofs without contradiction are seen as cleaner, so you might want to do the following: assume $m=nb+r$ with $0\leq r<b$, and then derive $a^r=1$, which directly implies $r=0$. However, your proof is certainly correct.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you work out the same thing as OP, $r = 0$ follows immediately from the fact that $b$ is the order of $a$.

Comment: It’s not whether proofs by contradiction or without are “cleaner” per se. It’s that here the assumption that $b$ does not divide $m$ is not used throughout the proof, except to contradict the conclusion that $b$ *does* divide $m$; so this. is really a direct proof disguised as a proof by contradiction. That’s what makes it “less clean”.